# very basic nginx rewrite

Tags: nginx

I want all request going to :  `http://domain/xyz`

to be proxied to

```
http://127.0.0.1:26991/SOME_RREFIX/xyz
```

This following rule is not doing it :

```
    location / {
        rewrite ^.*& /eq/$1;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:26991;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this configuration:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:26991/eq/;
}
```